# How to make a 5.1 and a 7.1 surround sound file

Tags: python, matlab, octave, surround

I'm trying to make/create a 5.1 and a 7.1 surround sound file but I'm having trouble finding a way to do it.  I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and I have access to octave / matlab / python.  I understand how to create an audio file in octave / matlab / python but not sure how to create the proper file format for a 5.1 and 7.1 surround file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to create 6 (for 5.1) or 8 (7.1) separate mono audio files, one for each loud speaker (front_left.wav, front_center.wav, ...), you can join them with the following command line:

```sh
ffmpeg -i front_left.wav -i front_right.wav -i front_center.wav -i lfe.wav -i back_left.wav -i back_right.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a]join=inputs=6:channel_layout=5.1:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR|2.0-FC|3.0-LFE|4.0-BL|5.0-BR[a]" -map "[a]" output.wav
```

This line is from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation that has several other useful channel manipulations examples. `LFE` (low frequency effects) is referring to the sub-woofer. [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) is available for Windows, Mac and Linux (e.g. as Debian package of the same name).

If you want to create a multichannel audio file directly from Python, have a look at the [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) package (which makes use of the ffmpeg library under the hood).

To probe whether a given audio file has multichannel content you can use `ffprobe` of the ffmpeg suite:

```sh
ffprobe -hide_banner output.wav
```

which shows e.g.:

```
Input #0, wav, from 'output.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.28, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Vorbis is the only free sound codec that supports surround-sound. There used to be some python projects to deal with this format, but they do not seem to be maintained any more.

You can try looking through these old projects (i.e. [pyvorbis](http://ekyo.nerim.net/software/pyogg/)).

Alternatively you can try using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10061-vorbis-ogg-audio-encodingdecoding) matlab project, and see if a vanilla 6-channel vorbis file will work with 5.1 surround sound (a quick glance at the [spec](http://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/Vorbis_I_spec.html) makes me think it should).

Comment: PCM RIFF should *technically* also be able to, but I don't know if there's any programs that could actually *read* it.